# IDA command bar default language

Tags: ida, idapython

The command bar at the bottom of the output window in IDA defaults to python. I would greatly prefer it to default to IDC, is there a way to change this default? I found one reference to `RunPlugin("python",4)` [in the idapython github repo](https://github.com/idapython/src#usage), but it's not clear where it should be used. Adding the following line to plugins.cfg also has no effect.

```
;plugin_name                     filename    hotkey  arg  flags
;------------------------------- ----------  ------  ---  --------
python                           python       0       3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the CLI language to IDC by clicking on the button to the left of the CLI, right click in the CLI input area and click the option marked `Default CLI`

[image]

[image]